# "This" in Typescript class instance

Tags: javascript, this, typescript

In javascript I could use either saving **this** to function-scoped **_this**, or binding function to **this** directly (Function.bind or underscorejs bind utilites).

But typescript is supposed to more object-oriented, and I was expecting **this** in typescript to point to the class instance. But it does work just as in JS. So I have to use construction

```
    export class Mouse {
        private board : Presentation.View.Board;
        private focus : Presentation.View.Element = null;
        constructor(board:Presentation.View.Board){
            var _this = this;
            board.bindMouse(
                function(event:JQueryEventObject){
                    if( _this.focus ) _this.focus.move(event);
                }
            );
        }
```

or

```
    export class Mouse {
        private board : Presentation.View.Board;
        private focus : Presentation.View.Element = null;
        constructor(board:Presentation.View.Board){
            var _this = this;
            board.bindMouse(
                _.bind(function(event:JQueryEventObject){
                    if( this.focus ) this.focus.move(event);
                }, this);
            );
        }
```

So I ask, are there any ways to avoid direct **this** micromanagement? I suppose there is a way to make some kind of augumentations so class instance always have some reference to inself (it can have any name, like **that**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arrow functions. Form the spec:

> A function expression using the function keyword introduces a new dynamically bound *this*, 
>   whereas an arrow function expression preserves the *this* of its enclosing context. 
>   Arrow function expressions are particularly useful for writing callbacks, which otherwise often
>   have an undefined or unexpected *this*.

```
 board.bindMouse((event: JQueryEventObject) => {
       if(this.focus) this.focus.move(event);
 });
```

Comment: I really dislike this C-type syntax, but looks like its only good option.

Comment: That is strange, as I understand most developers like the arrow syntax.